# Historical Development of PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I would be really thankful if someone could tell me good references giving development of techniques of Solving PDEs why such equations are important.

Regards,

Harish

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty detailed history of PDEs in the 20th century. The first few chapters give a nice early history and early applications of the subject without going into much mathematical detail and the subsequent chapters will give a fairly thorough history of its development.

http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~fazly/files/HistoryPDE.pdf

Edit: it seems that the previous link is now dead. Here is different excellent survey article on the modern development of PDEs: https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/evans_pcam.pdf